# Bidirectional operators

Tags: scala

Given the following n-dimensional data point:

```scala
class Point private (private val data: Array[Double]) {

  private def op(other: Point)(f: (Double, Double) => Double): Point = {
    for (i <- data.indices)
      data(i) = f(data(i), other.data(i))
    this
  }

  private def op(scalar: Double)(f: (Double, Double) => Double): Point = {
    for (i <- data.indices)
      data(i) = f(data(i), scalar)
    this
  }

  // Point scalar ops
  def +(scalar: Double): Point = op(scalar)(_ + _)
  def -(scalar: Double): Point = op(scalar)(_ - _)
  def *(scalar: Double): Point = op(scalar)(_ * _)
  def /(scalar: Double): Point = op(scalar)(_ / _)

  // Point Point ops
  def +(other: Point): Point = op(other)(_ + _)
  def -(other: Point): Point = op(other)(_ - _)
  def *(other: Point): Point = op(other)(_ * _)
  def /(other: Point): Point = op(other)(_ / _)


  override def toString: String = {
    "Point(" + data.map(_.toString).mkString(", ") + ")"
  }
}

object Point {
  def apply(data: Double*): Point = new Point(Array(data:_*))
}
```

I can do the following:

```scala
val p1 = Point(1,2,3)
println(p1 + 3) // Point(4.0, 5.0, 6.0)
```

But, I would also like to have a "bidirectional" behavior:

```scala
val p1 = Point(1,2,3)
println(3 + p1)
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Using an [**implicit class**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) to create a rich wrapper for *scalar* values.

```
implicit class ScalarOps (val scalar: Double) extends AnyVal {
  def + (point: Point): Point = point + scalar
  // Other methods...
}

val p = Point(1, 2, 3)
1 + p // res0: Point = Point(2, 3, 4)
```

Note that I combined the implicit class together with a [**value class**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), so your wrapper in most cases is not really instantiated.